# Slow wifi ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04, ralink

I realise similar questions have been posted a lot and I've tried the solutions I've seen suggested but to no avail. I have a Ralink RT5372 wireless adapter on Ubuntu 16.04 that is acting very slow. Additionally, I use the same adapter on windows via a dual-boot and don't experience the same issue. I've tried turning power management off, and I've also tried editing my nsswitch.conf file but neither have helped. To give you an idea of speed, it's maxing out at a few 100kbps per second. Thanks for any responses.

Comment: Is the driver *rt2800usb* ? Check: `lsmod | grep rt2` If so, please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep rt2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Is your wireless connection using WPA2-AES? Cheers, Al